# Using naming best practices in Vue.JS, should I use `template` or `view`?

Tags: vue.js, naming-conventions, directory-structure

I’m organizing my VueJS project folder. Which is the better choice, `templates` or `view`? That is,

```
/src
- /templates
  - Home.vue
  - Login.vue
  - /users
    - User.vue
```

or

```
/src
- /view
  - Home.vue
  - Login.vue
  - /users
    - User.vue
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best practice is to use views for your routes and components for your dumb or intelligent components.

Furthermore, I can suggest [this article](https://medium.com/js-dojo/architect-a-large-scale-vue-js-application-eaf90dc1da05) or [this one](https://www.maxpou.fr/3-tips-scaling-vue-application).